# Prevent jQuery automaticly redirecting after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an ajax call that loads a div into a popup, but when I click on button, the trigger happens, the div gets loaded then the entire page gets reloaded. I just wanted to know how could I find this second function that is reloading my entire page and add the exception, so that on me adding the div it does not trigger? I have tried return false and event.preventDefault(); but that didn't work

My AJAX call code is like this

```
        $('.trigger').on('click', function(){
          $.ajax({
            url: '../load_div.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
              data: data
            },
            datatype: 'JSON'
          }).done( function(data) {
              console.log(data);
              $('.div_class').html(data);
            });

          });
```

Comment: is .trigger a 'submit' button? If it is.. Just use a regular button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A submit button will automatically load another page.
to avoid this. You can use

```
<button type="button"></button>
```

or

```
<input type="button">
```

or in your event handler

```
$('.trigger').on('click', function(event){
   event.preventDefault(); //prevents page redirect
   $.ajax({
     url: '../load_div.php',
     type: 'POST',
     data: {
       data: data
     },
     datatype: 'JSON'
   }).done( function(data) {
       console.log(data);
       $('.div_class').html(data);
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it.